# Recursive Triggers in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-trigger

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`, `table2` have hierarchical data like below

```
  geo_id     parent_id
        1       NULL      
        2        1        
        3        2        
        4        3        
        5        3        
        6        3
```

and table1 has data like below

```
ID    geo_id
1       2      
2       3        
3       3        
4       3        
5       5       
6       5
```

finally I have below Update trigger,

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updateGeoHierarchyChilds] ON [dbo].[table2]
FOR UPDATE
AS
declare @ID int
BEGIN

 Declare VicIds CURSOR LOCAL FOR  SELECT geo_id from inserted
 OPEN VicIds
 FETCH NEXT  FROM VicIds into @ID
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
 BEGIN
 update table1
set anyCol=AnyValue // suppose setting any column
where geo_id=@ID
update table2
set anyCol=AnyValue // suppose setting any column
where parent_id=@ID


FETCH NEXT FROM VicIds INTO @ID
    END
 CLOSE VicIds
 DEALLOCATE VicIds
END
```

when I update table2 for example, I run below command stand alone

```
update table2
set anyCol=anyValue //this line is supposition for sake of example
where geo_id=2
```

it updates `table1` for `geo_id=2`
it also updates all child where `parent_id=2` in `table2`
but it not updating `table1` against childs of `geo_id=2`
simply saying,
When below portion of trigger called

```
update table2
set anyCol=AnyValue // suppose setting any column
where parent_id=@ID
```

it updates bunch of child records in same table, but child records not updating thier relation records in `table1`

Comment: TRIGGER [dbo].[updateGeoHierarchyChilds] ON [dbo].[table2] i suppose?

Comment: You do not need a cursor here. This could be turned into 2 simple update statements and forget the cursor entirely. Triggers are not going to run recursively. You need to make these updates in your code.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191520(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: yes @Serg its table2 ,I updated

Comment: @SeanLange it will lengthy in code, records will be updated from different front end app and this trigger will update data for my App. I have no access to main application, I have only access to DB,So i have to do it all in triggers somehow

Comment: OK but do your recursion in the trigger instead of trying to use recursive triggers.

Comment: @SeanLange is it possible to update records without using update DML command?indeed not, I think I have to call update command inside same trigger for same table. (Recursive updates)

Comment: Have you heard of a recursive cte? You don't have to use recursive triggers to do this kind of thing. Perhaps if you could share some table structures and sample data along with the desired results I could help.

Comment: is there any performance issue on using one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trigger will not recurse till you set an option

```
ALTER DATABASE [you db] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

Comment: it did something new, lemme check it doing the right thing