# How is this trigger not recursive?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, triggers, sql-update

I have a trigger which fires when `ListPrice` is updated and checks if percentage increase is more than 15% or not.

Inside the trigger logic, I am checking if `ListPrice` is updated and if percentage increase is more than 15%, I am updating list price with oldvalue form the deleted table else I am setting it to newvalue from inserted table.

In all cases `ListPrice` gets updated but the trigger does not fire recursively. Why is that happening?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Product_AfterUpdate
ON Production.Product
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT, @OldListPrice MONEY, @NewListPrice MONEY;

    SELECT @ID = del.ProductID, @OldListPrice = del.ListPrice 
    FROM deleted AS del;

    SELECT @NewListPrice = ins.ListPrice 
    FROM inserted AS ins;

    PRINT 'Trigger Fired' -- Only prints once

    IF UPDATE(ListPrice) -- Check if ListPrice is being updated
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Production.Product   
        SET ListPrice = CASE
                            WHEN (@NewListPrice - @OldListPrice) > (@OldListPrice * 0.15) -- Check for > 15% increase
                                THEN @OldListPrice
                                ELSE @NewListPrice
                        END
        WHERE ProductID = @ID
    END
END
```

Comment: The trigger is *fatally flawed*; it assumes a  `UPDATE` only *ever* effects one row. An `UPDATE` effects 0+ rows.

Comment: As a separate note, dispite its name, `money` is *not* a good data type for monetary data.

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is to throw an exception. For example `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d ON d.YourPrimaryKey = i.YourPrimaryKey WHERE (i.ListPrice - d.ListPrice) > (i.ListPrice * 0.15)) THROW 50001, 'Price increase too large', 1;` This will automatically rollback the whole transaction and throw an error back to the user.

Comment: I want to now If I am updating the same table inside a trigger then why the update trigger does not run again?

Comment: Perhaps the database has disabled recursive triggers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230888/13061224

Comment: @siggemannen I checked and it was disabled. Thanks for the help!